# Windows XP VPN. I have no idea

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2000, linksys

Some background info:

We recently relocated our main server from one office (office1) to another office (office2) (more people worked at the office2 than office1 so it made sense). We didn't have VPN set up before (remote users just used RDP) so before the move I set it up (office2 VPN to office1) just to make sure it would work....and it did. However, we had a WRT56G router at office1 and I didn't need to change anything in the router's config. Now that the machine has been relocated it doesn't work.

---

So, I need to set up a VPN from a Windows XP Pro (SP3) machine to access a network with a Linksys RV042 router and Windows Server 2000 (using active directory) behind it.

I've been at it for about 5 hours now with no luck.

I've:

- updated the RV042 router to the latest firmware.
- forwarded both TCP and UDP port 1723 to my Windows 2000 Server's internal IP
- enabled "PPTP Server" and added a User (with the same Username and password as a domain account on the server)
- enabled "PPTP Pass Through"
- disabled DHCP on the router (and tried it with DHCP enabled)
- disabled the router's firewall completely.

I don't know if these settings cause problems:

- DMZ is set up to point to some other system (security cameras, I think)
- The server's subnet used to be 192.168.100.* now it is 192.168.4.*

What else do I need to do?

Comment: I see a problem with DMZ. Unless you can add a rule specifically forwarding GRE to the VPN server, DMZ is your only remaining hope. See question https://serverfault.com/questions/37635/nat-gre-ip-protocol-47-over-linux-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set up the PPTP server on the linksys then the linksys router becomes the PPTP server, NOT the windows box. See
  http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wired-Routers/How-to-Setup-RV042-with-PPTP-The-Intended-way/td-p/175352

for details on how to set up PPTP passthrough (or use the linksys rv042 itself as the PPTP server).

HTH,

JJK

Comment: I was wondering about that. The information provided on the  `more...` link on the `PPTP Server` page hinted that PPTP allows for Windows Server 2000 PPTP. I can't remember the exact terms it used (I can't log in to the remote site ATM to check). I'll definitely try again tomorrow though!

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can buy WTRG-54 routers now with DD-WRT already on them.  Maybe you could buy a second one and then create a site-to-site VPN bridge  (instead of using that Linksys RV042 thing you mentioned) :  [Bridging DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN_-_Site-to-Site_Bridged_VPN_Between_Two_Routers)