# Linux GRE Tunnel: Remote Address parameter

Tags: linux-networking, nat, tunneling, gre

The Linux GRE tunnel as two parameters, local address and remote address. Suppose I have two routers, the left one is outside of a NAT and right one is inside NAT, then I want to create a GRE tunnel between the left and right routers. I am clear to the right side, where local address should be own address and remote address should be the peer public address. But the to the left side, I think the router will not know the peer address before the connection, then how would I set the 'remote' address for it?

Thanks in advance.
-woody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do as expected for other protocols: put only public IPs for remotes.

Example:

`left`: 192.0.2.10

NAT system: 198.51.100.20 / 192.168.0.1

`right` (behind NAT): 192.168.0.30

(And eg you're setting up tunnel's IPs for `left` 10.10.10.1/24 and `right` 10.10.10.2/24, it doesn't matter here)

You need to tell the `left` router that the `remote` is 198.51.100.20, while for the `right` router, the `remote` is 192.0.2.10.

Now the caveat: it really depends on settings on the NAT system *in case it's running Linux*.

If this NAT system is also Linux,

- It must of course at least do SNAT/MASQUERADE for `right` for protocol gre (47) in case it doesn't have a generic rule (but see later),
- while NAT for usual protocols usually pulls the related conntrack modules automatically, this doesn't happen for GRE. You have to [manually do `modprobe nf_conntrack_proto_gre`](https://serverfault.com/a/752996/217515), or no NAT will happen, and the tunnel won't work. Strangely, from tests, `nf_nat_proto_gre` doesn't seem needed (nor is enough alone).
- If there is no equivalent `DNAT` to the `SNAT/MASQUERADE`, then only `right` should initiate traffic to `left`. If `left` sends traffic to `right` (actually to the NAT system) after inactivity, this won't work, and the conntrack entry might prevent for up to 30s (after end of attempts) `right` to establish traffic to `left`. Once "established", the "OK" timer rises to 180s. So you should really consider adding a `DNAT` rule from `left` to `right` to complete the opposite `SNAT/MASQUERADE` rule.

On such Linux NAT system, you can verify what's happening using `conntrack -L -p gre`, it must have an entry after GRE tunnel activity or the correct module is missing.

Comment: Can I understand that in whatever SNAT/DNAT setups, there is only one host on the right side can do GRE with a same left side host?

Comment: Another question that related to the left side.  In the real world, it is a Cisco router. I has to support more than 1000 hosts to create GRE with each of them.  I don't know any detail inside the Cisco router, but to me it will be very strange if the router need to config GRE entries for all of these 1000 hosts. I image that there could exist an automatic way of doing it in Cisco, if so, which must be so different with the local/remote way of configuring found in Linux.  I have no info on this however, does someone know some of these for Cisco?  Thanks.

Comment: No idea on Cisco at all, but a normal NAT both ways is good enough if there's only *one* right system. Nothing special about "protocol 47" for its *IP* part. I was just warning of a slight lack of expected implicit feature on Linux

Comment: Btw, I tested it just to be sure before answering. If you think I addressed the question, don't forget to accept it